# load testing through wifi/lan + vpn

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, web-api-testing

I really did not found answer on my question in the web. I am currently doing load tests for a web service, for example: how service will handle 15 threads in 1 seconds, for that I use Jmeter. I always get different average response times for 15 threads. When I'm in my company's inner network, I get wonderful results, but when I am at home, using lan/wifi + vpn to get access to that web services, I get horrible results. When I test it through vpn, web service can not handle 30 threads in 1 seconds, average response time is like 13 seconds, otherwise from company's network, average response time is 4-5 seconds. Also, that web service, would be also called from a system using vpn.
My question is, what is correct result and correct way to test it. Test it from company's network, or though vpn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response time consists of the following metrics:

1. [Connect time](https://varvy.com/performance/tcp-connection-time.html)
2. [Latency](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) (also known as [Time To First Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte))
3. [Time to last byte](https://www.dareboost.com/en/doc/website-speed-test/metrics/time-to-last-byte-ttlb)

So my expectation is that it's not the high response time, it's more about bandwidth of your ISP and VPN connections, theoretically you can subtract these connect time and the time for the packets to travel back and forth and get the "real" response time, however a better idea would be setting up a [remote JMeter slave](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) to be "local" to the system under test and orchestrate it from your "remote" JMeter master host, this way you will be able to obtain "clean" results without these network-related slow downs.

More information: [Apache JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

Comment: But, I think that setting up "local" will be not the correct result. I mean, that web service will be integrated in some application and it will use vpn to access that service. So, users who will try to access that service, the application will make a request and get a response through vpn, also its network will go through mobile network "LTE"

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, the correct way to test it should be the way your users are accessing your web service.

If the majority of users are accessing it through a VPN from outside, then test it that way; if it is the other way around test it from the company's network.
In the case of mixed access, you might want to test both at the same time.

Comment: the applications will use that service through vpn to access

Comment: Each user in real use will probably have their own VPN link but when load testing then all simulated users would use the same VPN link, such a test would not mimic reality. If each simulated user could use a different VPN link then the test might be valid.